# Content not filling CSS grid columns properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a lot of trouble displaying a "posts feed" in a static page on wordpress. I made a grid columns display that autofits the number of columns depending on the size of the screen, but when it reaches a certain screen size, the post content no longer fills its assigned space, and i dont know how to fix it.

the problematic page is this: https://auroranislands.com/spellbook/air-arcana/

I am pulling the post content with this simple shortcode:

```html
[display-posts category="Air Arcana" posts_per_page="-1" include_content="true" wrapper="div"]
```

and the CSS im using to display it is this one:

```css
div.display-posts-listing {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px,1fr));
 column-gap: 15px;
 column-rule: none;
}

div.listing-item {
 clear: both;
 margin: 9px 0;
 overflow: auto;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: lightgray;
}

div.listing-item a.image {
 display: none;
}

div.listing-item a.title {
 display: none;
}

div.listing-item span.excerpt-dash {
 display: none;
}

div.listing-item span.excerpt {
 display: none;
}
```

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Your code does NOT demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: im sorry, i dont know what part of the code is causing this behaviour, thats why im asking :c

I put the link on the page because the issue goes away if you resize the window to be small enough, and thats the strange part.

Comment: We can't use shortcodes or PHP in snippets, put some **actual output HTML**.

Comment: im new to html, i dont know how to do that, im sorry :C

Comment: the div with the content inside listing-item div has "content" class - http://joxi.ru/BA05qMJCJ60QNr which width is set to 67.5% remove this class and all is good - http://joxi.ru/1A5KEy0HnLoa0m

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your source and you seem to have a div with a class called 'content' around your tables, this div is restricting your tables to 67.5% width. If you remove the 'content ' class or override the width property. your code should work fine.
[content class restricting the width of table elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umHYP.png)